# update the value of key in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to build a dictionary to count the number of different colors of different fruit. Can I build a dictionary term like this?

```
dicts['apple'] = (('red',1),('green',2))
```

here `('red',1)` means the number of red apples is 1, `('green',2)` means the number of green apples is 2. If then I find another red apple, so I want to update the `('red',1) to ('red',2)`, is it possible? If it is, can you give a code example to implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to use nested dictionary, something like this

```
fruits = {"apple": {"red": 2, "green": 5},
          "grapes": {"red": 6, "green": 0}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a dictionary that has dictionaries as values (i.e. a nested dictionary) e.g.

```
fruits = { 'apple' : { 'red' : 1, 'green' : 2 },
           'pear' : { 'bartlett' : 2, 'packham' : 4 }
         }
```

To increment the number of red apples and packham pears:

```
fruits['apple']['red'] += 1 
fruits['pear']['packham'] += 2
print(fruits)
```

Output:

```
{
 'pear': {'packham': 6, 'bartlett': 2},
 'apple': {'green': 2, 'red': 2}
}
```